# How to get placemark address output in to single UITextfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I am following http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CurrentAddress/Listings/Classes_MapViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009469-Classes_MapViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6

this is tutorial for MKreversGeocoder. 
My question is how to get placemark address in to single textfield. As above tutorial is taking address in to tableview. please suggest me the code as this is requirement of my project. This might be simple but still I want the specific answer. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily accomplished by building up an NSMutableString to hold the address properties of MKPlacemark and then assigning this string to the textfield.  What exactly in this process don't you understand?